# django form wizard, ValidationError: ['ManagementForm data is missing or has been tampered.']

Tags: python, django, forms

I'm using django wizard for a multiple form signup which in the end will be 4 or 5 pages of forms. However I'm getting validation errors that may relate to the form action somehow, which I'm not sure how to solve.

The error seems to stem from line 282 here: https://github.com/django/django-formtools/blob/master/formtools/wizard/views.py
but I'm not clear on what's causing it?

(note I'm using django crispy forms but may not be relevant)

views.py

```
class SignupWizard(SessionWizardView):
    def get_template_names(self):
        return [TEMPLATES[self.steps.current]]

    def done(self, form_list, **kwargs):
        for form in form_list:
            if isinstance(form, SignupForm):
                user = form.save(self.request)
                complete_signup(self.request, user, settings.ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION, settings.LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL)
            else:
                other_signup_form = form.save(commit=False)
                user = self.request.user
                other_signup_form.user = user
                other_signup_form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(settings.LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL)


signup_view = SignupWizard.as_view(SIGNUP_FORMS)
```

forms.py

```
class SignupForm(allauthforms.SignupForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper(self)
        self.helper.label_class = 'sr-only'
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            Field('name', placeholder='Your Name'),
            PrependedText('email', '<i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i>', placeholder="Your Email",
                          autofocus=""),
            PrependedText('password1', '<i class="fa fa-key"></i>', placeholder="Enter Password"),
            Submit('sign_up', 'Sign up', css_class="btn btn-block btn-cta-primary"),
            )

class SignupForm2(forms.Form):
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30)
```

template:

```
{% block inner %}
    <h2 class="title text-center">Sign up now</h2>
    <p class="intro text-center">It only takes 2 minutes.</p>
    <div class="row">
          {% crispy form %}        
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The form wizard requires that you include the management form in the form tag in your template:

```
{{ wizard.management_form }}
```

See [the docs](http://django-formtools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/wizard.html?highlight=management_form#creating-templates-for-the-forms) for more info.

Comment: Thanks Alasdair, that worked perfectly, I hadn't realised more would be needed in the templates, thanks for the link.